# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'then' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to chain some events together so that each function will run after the previous one has finished. This is how I have it:

```
function siteUsage() {
    // Do Something
}
function siteTerms() {
    // Do Something
}
function siteSources() {
    // Do Something
}

siteUsage().then(siteTerms()).then(siteSources());
```

But I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'then' of undefined
```

Any ideas?
Am I also going about this the right way, I mean chaining Ajax requests like this?

**EDIT**

Here is one of the functions in its entirety. Incase you need to see what it does.

```
function siteUsage() {

        $.getJSON('charts_ajax.php',{a : 'visits', rangeStartDate : '<?=$_POST["rangeStartDate"] ?>', rangeEndDate : '<?= $_POST["rangeEndDate"] ?>'}, function(data){
            if(data){
                var tableHtml = '<tbody><tr><td class="id" width="20%">Visits</td><td width="20%">' + data.visits + '</td><td width="60%">A visit is a single-user session.</td></tr>' +
                    '<tr><td class="id">New Visits</td><td width="20%">' + data.newVisits + '%</td><td>The percentage of visits marked as first-time visits.</td></tr></tbody>' +
                    '<tr><td class="id">Page Views</td><td>' + data.pageViews + '</td><td>Views of each individual page.</td></tr>' +
                    '<tr><td class="id">Average Pages per Visit</td><td>' +  data.avgPageViews + '</td><td>Page Views divided by Visits</td></tr>' +
                    '<tr><td class="id">Average Time On Site</td><td>' + data.avgTime + '</td><td>The average duration of visitor sessions.</td></tr>' +
                    '<tr><td class="id">Visitors</td><td>' + data.totalVisits + '</td><td>Total number of visitors to your website for the requested time period.</td></tr>' +
                    '<tr><td class="id">Visits from Mobile Devices</td><td colspan="2"><div style="position:relative; background:#9fb7cb; height:22px;"><span style="width:' + data.yesMobile + '%; background:#003F75; height:22px; display:inline-block; border-right:1px solid #fff;"></span><span style="font-size:85%; position:absolute; left:8px; top:4px; color:#fff; text-shadow:0 1px 0 #003F75; width:80px;"><strong>Yes:</strong> ' + data.yesMobile + '</span><span style="font-size:85%; position:absolute; right:8px; top:4px; color:#003F75;"><strong>No: </strong>' + data.noMobile + '</span></div></td></tr>';

                $('#usage-table').html(tableHtml).find('.spinner').stop();

            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: Without knowing the return value of the functions it's impossible to help.

Comment: There is no then in javascript based on your tagging or described code

Comment: One of your functions (probably siteUsage) is returning undefined instead of a promise. Do you know how to use the debugger in your browser? It helps a lot for things like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

siteUsage has to return either a promise object or a deferred object. For example,

```
function siteUsage() {
    return $.getJSON(...);
}
function siteTerms() {
    return $.getJSON(...);
}
function siteSources() {
    return $.getJSON(...);
}

siteUsage().then(siteTerms).then(siteSources);
```

Additionally, as you can see in my code, .then accepts a function, therefore you'll want to pass the function rather than execute it (unless the function returns a function, which is unlikely for this use case)

Comment: Do the function calls not require parenthesis?

Comment: May be you intended `siteUsage()`

Comment: They do not, otherwise they would execute too early.

Comment: Ah I wasnt aware it was supposed to return anything, What these functions do is make an ajax call then populate some tables. How would you go about loading my functions like this one after another.

Comment: ... Just like i have done, i don't see anything in your code that would prevent you from doing this.

Comment: My mistake - of course siteTerms and siteSources wouldn't need parenthesis, but surely siteUsage would, or it would never execute?

Comment: Thank you - I didn't know if I was right or not.  I'm happy with the confirmation :)

Comment: Yeah, it was just a typo, i didn't see it so i wasn't sure what you two were talking about.